# how to update ArrayList <Bitmap> after photo deletion?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

So I am populating my Bitmap ArrayList (photos) by adding images through gallery and camera photos and then saves the array of names into database and images into the storage. In the ImageAdapter class if I remove an image from the array list then without saving the list it successfully removes the image from the storage but if I click the save button then it did not remove the image from my internal phone storage as my Bitmap ArrayList (photos) does not update.  How can I update my Arraylist of Bitmap in the main class (fragment) before saving?

Save function

```
public void saveNotes() {

   if (!Modify) {
       if (titulo.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
           if (!base.buscarNota(titulo.getText().toString())) {
               String almostSameText = Html.toHtml(texto.getEditableText()).toString();
               if (bp != null) {
                   Util.saveToInternalStorage(context, bp, ArrayImageName, photos);
                   Notas notas = new Notas(titulo.getText().toString().trim(), almostSameText, getFecha(), stringForArray);
                   base.insertarNota(notas);
               } else {
                   Notas notas = new Notas(titulo.getText().toString().trim(), almostSameText, getFecha(), null);
                   base.insertarNota(notas);
               }
               getActivity().onBackPressed();
           } else {
               Alerta alerta = new Alerta(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.title_existente));
           }
       } else {
           Alerta alerta = new Alerta(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.title_vacio));
       }
   } else {
       String almostSameText = Html.toHtml(texto.getEditableText()).toString();
       if (bp != null) {
           Util.saveToInternalStorage(context, bp, ArrayImageName, photos);
           base.modificarNota(titulo.getText().toString().trim(), almostSameText, stringForArray, id);
       } else {
           base.modificarNota(titulo.getText().toString().trim(), almostSameText, null, id);
       }
       getActivity().onBackPressed();
       getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_from_right);
   }
```

}

my ImageAdapter Delete bitmap class

```
public void showDeletePictureDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Imagecontext);
    } else {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Imagecontext);
    }
    builder.setTitle("Delete photo")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this photo?")
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // continue with delete
                    ImageFileArrayAfterDelete = EditorFragment.loadImageStrings;
                    String folder_main = "MyImages";
                    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), folder_main);
                    z = new File(f.toString(), Uri.parse(String.valueOf(ImageFileArrayAfterDelete.get(currentPosition))) + ".jpg");
                    ImageName = z.getName();
                    Log.d("TAG_", "Position is: " + currentPosition + " File name is: " + ImageName);
                    bpAdapter.remove(currentPosition);
                    ImageFileArrayAfterDelete.remove(currentPosition);
                    toSingleString();
                    notifyItemRemoved(currentPosition);
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(currentPosition, bpAdapter.size());
                    z.delete();
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this just by doing this after deleting the item from your list

```
    myList.removeAt(position)
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```